# Why does Jaccard similarity score is the same as accuarcy score in binary classification?

Tags: classification, evaluation

In sklearn document (https://scikit-learn.org/0.15/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.jaccard_similarity_score.html), it said:

`In binary and multiclass classification, this function is equivalent to the accuracy_score. It differs in the multilabel classification problem.`

However, according to the Jaccard index on Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index)

[image]

It clearly differs from the accuracy score ((TP+TN)/(TP+FP+FN+TN)).

Might someone explain me that's which is correct, and why?

Answer (score 1):

The 0.15 documentation is outdated, check the stable version that no longer points out [`metrics.jaccard_score`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.jaccard_score.html#sklearn.metrics.jaccard_score) is the same as accuracy for binary classification.